# ogr2ogr producing different results on different system

Tags: postgresql, postgis, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to convert the shape file which represents the administrative area of `Philippines` into geojson. I'm getting the shape file from [here](http://www.diva-gis.org/datadown) . The file I'm trying to convert is this `PHL_adm3.shp` .

I'm using this bash script:

```
function shp2geojson() {
      ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON "$1.geojson" "$1.shp"
}

for var in *.shp; do shp2geojson ${var%\.*}; done
```

I ran this script on my server and got the corresponding geojson file. Now I ran the same script on my local and the geometry for many cities were different in my local than what was on my server. Though the coordinates do not differ much, they only differ after 6-7 places of decimal, but they throw an exception when I try to insert them in `PostGIS`.

Here's an example of the geometry that is producing error on server while inserting it in PostGIS. I'm also posting the geometry that I'm getting on my local of the same city.

Server: [Geometry](http://pastebin.com/kWypUjT0)

Local: [Geometry](http://pastebin.com/kWypUjT0)

I also ran `ST_IsValidReason` on both geometries. I got the following error on my server.

```
SELECT ST_IsValidReason(ST_SetSRID(
            ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(my_geometry),4326))

Server : Error [('Self-intersection[120.979159 14.71218]',)]
Local  : [('Valid Geometry',)]
```

I tried the exact same thing on different countries like India, Japan Thailand and for all those countries that I tested, the same thing was happening. On local I didn't found any error but on my server I was getting Invalid geometry.

Can anyone explain what's wrong with my queries and how to fix this ?

P.S.- Both of my systems are 64 bit and running Ubuntu 14.04.